# How to repeatedly execute one yield step in a generator?

Tags: python, http, generator

I am writing tests that involve HTTP requests. There are some requests I have to make in a certain order, but I want to check the response from each step. So I thought a generator would be appropriate to enforce the sequence:

```
# Main code

def sequence_of_requests(arg1, arg2):

    yield request_a(arg1)
    yield request_b(arg1, arg2)
    yield request_c(arg1, arg2)
```

Then in my test code I can write:

```
# Test code

generator_responses = sequence_of_requests()

r = next(generator_responses)
assert r.status_code == 200

r = next(generator_responses)
assert r.status_code == 204

r = next(generator_responses)
assert r.status_code == 404
```

The problem is that `request_c()` does not always receive the correct status on the first try, so I have been wrapping this function with a decorator in the test code so it repeatedly tries until success or timeout.

I'm wondering if there's some way I can do this wrapping on the generator, so I still get the enforced sequence of events. So I'm basically wondering if there's some way to repeatedly call one yield step of a generator.

Note: I don't want to put the code to wait for a response directly in the `sequence_of_requests` function, because it's not test code. The `sequence_of_requests` function is just used to ensure those steps are completed in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of yielding the response values themselves, you can yield the functions, which can then be called repeatedly. The parameters to the functions can be applied with `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial


def sequence_of_requests(arg1, arg2):

    yield partial(request_a, arg1)
    yield partial(request_b, arg1, arg2)
    yield partial(request_c, arg1, arg2)
```

Now the steps can be tested:

```
generator_functions = sequence_of_requests()

r = next(generator_functions)()
assert r.status_code == 200

r = next(generator_functions)()
assert r.status_code == 204

# Repeatedly make the request until the expected status code is returned.
func_slow_request = next(generator_functions)
wait_for_status(404)(func_slow_request)
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren't very specific about timeout and number of retries, or condition for success... But, for simplicity, let's assume you want to retry up to 5 times, with 1s in between retries and you're expecting an error code other than 500 (or 5xx) to proceed.

Then you could use something like:

```
import time

def sequence_of_requests(arg1, arg2):
    yield request_a(arg1)
    yield request_b(arg1, arg2)
    for retries in range(5):
        result = request_c(arg1, arg2)
        if result.status_code < 500:
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    yield result
```

If you get to the maximum number of retries, you'll simply return the last received response. If you get a valid response, you break out of the loop and return the good response.

There's a small inefficiency in that if you reach the total number of retries, you still sleep for 1s before returning the value. You can fix that by managing the `retries` variable explicitly and checking for the limit inside the loop. But you might have other ideas on how to manage giving up (e.g. a timeout, rather than a fixed number of retries), so you should adapt that part of the code to follow the logic that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't specific about that because I though it wasn't relevant. I already have a decorator to wait for a response, given a number of attempts and a wait time. I only want to wait for a response in the tests, not in the main code. I edited the question to make this clearer.